# ¿Por qué esto está mal escrito (es SQL)?

Tags: mysql

Es para crear el usuario root; esto es por que laravel me devuelve un error de autenticación y buscando me encontré con esto.

```
CREATE USER 'dbuser1'@'< Host IP >' IDENTIFIED VIA  
mysql_native_password USING '***';  
 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \*.* TO 'dbuser1'@'< Host IP >' REQUIRE NONE  
WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0  
MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Comment: "Laravel me devuelve un error de autenticación": no olvides mostrar qué error te está retornando Laravel. ¿Da un error de sintaxis?

Comment: [¿Estás con PHPMyAdmin?](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14217)